# How to release NSManagedObjectContext's retained deletedObjects without saving it

Tags: ios, core-data

I've recently come across a behavior that is pretty much guaranteed to leak objects in a pretty common usage pattern of CoreData:

1. Saving background contexts to the store
2. Having a viewContext automatically merge changes from the store

When the viewContext merges changes, it keeps deleted objects around in its `deletedObjects` property. These are only cleared when the viewContext saves.

However it's my understanding that one of the objectives of this pattern is having the viewContext be read-only in order to more easily reason about what's going on and avoid conflicts with background contexts.
If there's no other way to deal with this, it seems that any pattern where a merging context is read-only is destined to leak.

Would appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Why does `viewContext` (the main queue context) have to be read-only? (not to be confused by the property being read-only)

Comment: It doesn't have to, but it's quite common to want that to be the case like I said. Generally if you're doing heavy object parsing before creating your objects, it's common to want to do that on background contexts, save them and have `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` set to `true` on the viewContext. This extremely common scenario will leak until you save the viewContext, which you have no logical reason to want to do in this case.